# @polymer/lit-element has been deprecated

Tags: polymer, lit-element

I am using @polymer/lit-element for my application.Recently I did `npm install` 
which led to following error

```
"npm WARN deprecated @polymer/lit-element@0.5.2: @polymer/lit-element has moved to lit-element. Please uninstall this package and install lit-element. See https://www.polymer-project.org/blog/2019-01-11-lit-element-rc".
```

When I checked my node_modules, the lit-element folder had been deleted from @polymer folder.Is there any way that I can get back my @polymer/lit-element?
( Apart from the point that I have to migrate whole my application to lit-element which sounds tedious )

Comment: use `npm install --save lit-element` at the root of your project. You will have the two directory under node_module like `lit-html` and `lit-element` then just change the path something like `import { LitElement, html } from  '..\node_modules\lit-element\lit-element.js'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`npm WARN deprecated @polymer/lit-element@0.5.2` is a warning not an error. [v0.5.2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@polymer/lit-element/v/0.5.2) is still available for use. You can `npm install` to install the dependencies listed in your `package.json` or if `@polymer/lit-element` is not listed in in `package.json` you can add it with `npm install --save @polymer/lit-element@0.5.1`.

That being said `@polymer/lit-element` is deprecated and being replaced with `lit-element`. You should replace `@polymer/lit-element` with `lit-element` within `package.json` and your codebase.

Comment: Small update to this answer as of 2022.  `lit-element` is now contained in the lit package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/lit

It can be imported with `import { html, LitElement } from 'lit';`